# Masked Textbox with alphanumeric characters only

Tags: wpf, maskedtextbox

I want to implement something like when a user enters 4 characters then hyphen should come automatically. After every 4 characters hyphen should get inserted. Maximum 16 characters allowed excluding hyphen. For Example :
ABCD-56GH-FG3W-JKGF
I am using wpf masked textbox. But I am getting few problems which are listed below :

1. I need to hide the hyphen which is present in mask.
2. Need to handle the cursor position. I am able to move the cursor to any position. In actual it should always be at the left side but if text is there then we can move the cursor to anywhere in between the text.
3. On paste textbook should only take alphanumeric characters only with without hyphen . For Eg : Either ABCD-56GH-FG3W-JKGF or ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
4. Also the text is not getting started from the center of the masked textbox.

I want the behavior same as we have in windows Add product key dialog box.
Attaching the screenshot :
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2446/6fY8Oe.png

Comment: This is the code I am using :
<xctk:MaskedTextBox TextAlignment="Center" Text="" Name="maskedTxtBox" CharacterCasing="Upper" PromptChar=" " PreviewMouseDown="MaskedTxtBox_PreviewMouseDown" FontSize="25" PreviewKeyDown="MaskedTxtBox_PreviewKeyDown" MouseEnter="MaskedTxtBox_MouseEnter" Opacity="1" Mask="AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA" Margin="40,87,61,130"/>

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this ?